# Turing a Seagate HDD on/off after 1 min

Tags: hard-drive, external-hard-drive

I know there is a lot of discussion regarding whether a hard drive should be kept running  at all times or turn off after a certain time

I purchased a Seagate HDD (https://www.amazon.ca/dp/B07CRG7BBH/ref=twister_B08N2C8M21?_encoding=UTF8&psc=1), and currently I have it set to turn off after every 1 minute because I do not use it often (I access it once every 1 hr.). I don't really mind the power consumption I just really care about longevity cause I do not have a backup system like RAID. so is this a stupid idea or is it alright?

Comment: Smart drive, if it's Turing.

Comment: So far.. I have yet to see anything "smart".. from my experience, the windows explorer (or one of many third party extensions beyond MS control) will query the drive periodically forcing you to wait for it to spin up.  Play with it.. see if it pisses you off.. mine did. :^P

Comment: Hello Moab, yes it kind of just cements the same points I have heard before, but I was hoping to find someone who has experience with Seagate (because I know their drives are on the mid-lower end of the spectrum). And sorry I have no experience with smart drives, I have been looking in Canadian websites but haven't found many.

Comment: I've had drives constantly spinning for 12 years & still working fine. Conversely I've had drives that failed after 6 months. *You won't know when it will fail until it fails*. All you ever need is a good backup strategy. Trying to 'protect' a structure against failure with no backup only prolongs the time to disappointment, it doesn't avoid it.

Comment: I just looked at the link - it's an external, it will constantly spin. You can't spin down drives over USB.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik - I see what you did there. LOL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes the operating system or some programs access the disks, you should check if actually the disk is turned on only once every hour (you should be able to tell by the slight vibrations it produces).

If it turns on only once every hour, there will be no problems; if it turns on every 2 minutes, it's better you keep it always on, until you find what is waking it from sleep.

Comment: I just looked at the link - it's an external, it will constantly spin. You can't spin down drives over USB.

Comment: I'm pretty sure some can be spin down